# Highstock Candlestick connect nulls or zero's

Tags: highcharts

I have a candlestick chart with 1 hour intervals. I receive the data like this:

```
[ [ 1400760000000,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [ 1400763600000,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [ 1400767200000,
    20,
    21,
    20,
    20
  ],
  [ 1400770800000,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [ 1400774400000,
    19,
    19,
    19,
    19
  ],
  [ 1400778000000,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ]
]
```

or I can receive the data like this:

```
[ [ 1400760000000,
    null
  ],
  [ 1400763600000,
    null
  ],
  [ 1400767200000,
    20,
    21,
    20,
    20
  ],
  [ 1400770800000,
    null
  ],
  [ 1400774400000,
    19,
    19,
    19,
    19
  ],
  [ 1400778000000,
    null
  ]
]
```

Is there any way to connect the nulls or zero's?

I've tried setting the `connectNulls` options to true in `series` like this:

```
series : [{
    type : 'candlestick',
    name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
    connectNulls: true,
    data : data
}]
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a null for each parameter `(open, close, high, low)` like in the example

http://jsfiddle.net/22mrT/